# Eliminar evento jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, function

Buenas tardes, mi duda es la siguiente, se genera código en algún lado al momento de trabajar con php,jquery,html ya que como con jquery estaba jugando con los eventos para manejar algunas acciones, y en mi código puse un evento keypress para que me detectará al presionar la tecla enter y me mostrará un alert con x mensaje, quite ese fragmento de código y salve, mas sin embargo este alert sigue apareciendo cuando presiono enter, aunque las lineas de código que activaban dicho evento ya no se encuentran en el documento, tal ves es una duda tonta, pero no encuentro como quitarlo.

Comment: El codigo es en una pagina web? O es en un script file?

Comment: tengo mi index.html y ahi indico el uso del archivo que contiene el codigo javascript

Comment: Borra temporales (HISTORIAL Y ESAS COSAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SI ESTAS SEGURO QUE NO ESTAS LLAMANDO EL CÓDIGO EN NINGÚN MOMENTO. BORRA LOS DATOS DEL NAVEGADOR.... CIÉRRALO..... LA CACHE DE LOS NAVEGADORES PUEDE PRODUCIR QUE ASI AUNQUE TU GUARDES NO TOMA LOS CAMBIOS ESPECIALMENTE LO DE JS Y CSS.... ENTONCES PUEDES HACER ESO... O SI NO QUIERES BORRAR LOS DATOS PRUEBA TU PROYECTO EN OTRO NAVEGADOR ESTE NO TENDRÁ ESE PROBLEMA

Comment: Gracias! le pase el cleanner para limpiarlo y funcionó, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿ En mayúsculas ? ¿ A grito *pelao* ? Venga ya, hombre. -1

Comment: jajaja no pues gracias......

Answer (score 0):

Antes del evento ponte esto:

```
$("#ID o SELECTOR").unbind('keypress');
```

evitas el doble fire...

ten cuidado de que el javascript no este en el cache del navegador.

Comment: Era el cache del navegador, gracias por su apoyo.